# Loading stylesheet dependant on User Agent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to load a different Stylesheet depending on whether the User Agent is an iPad or other.  I know that generally, detecting browsers isn't the most fantastic idea and will probably cripple our maintainability sometime in the future..not my decision.

So here we have some JavaScript to detect the user agent.  It isn't working.  I may have mis-escaped something.   The error I am getting is a red herring (object reference), but only shows up when I execute the JavaScript.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('ready fired');
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") != -1) {
            //alert('bleep bloop blop...iPad detected');
            var stringToWrite = '<script src=\'\<\%\= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/iscroll.js") \%\>\' type="text/javascript"><\/script>';
            stringToWrite += '<link href=\'\<\%\= ResolveUrl("~/Stylesheets/scrollbar.css") \%\>\' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" \/>';
            stringToWrite += '<link href=\'\<\%\= ResolveUrl("~/Stylesheets/iPadCommon.css") \%\>\' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" \/>';
            alert(stringToWrite);
            document.write(stringToWrite);
        }
        //else
        //alert('bleep bloop blop...who cares browser');
    });
```

Comment: Is the issues with your userAgent? does `alert('bleep bloop blop...iPad detected');` get called (if not commented out)?

Comment: personally I would want to do that kind of check using a server side language.

Comment: @Peppered Lemons - yea it gets called.  Detection is fine.  Must be my string escaping.  Wish there was an auto-escape this crappy string for javascript webapp online.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to escape something used server side — `<%` (ASP or JSP or something). Since it is escaped, it doesn't get processed server side. Since the client can't execute it, when the JS writes it, the browser just treats it as invalid HTML.

Comment: And yes, this will come back to bite you. Just use media queries, its much saner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should consider detecting the agent on the server side, otherwise it won't work for browsers which have javascript disabled.

Comment: +1 I am starting to see why I should do this irregardless of what I've been told.  @Quentin has a good point.

Answer (score 2):

found this at random on the internet:

```
//returns true if user is using one of the following mobile browsers
var ismobile=navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should use `@media handheld` to use style rules specific to handheld devices.

If that it too course, i.e. if you need different CSS for iPad vs. iPhone vs. Android, you should do a server-side detect and add CSS classes to the `<html>` and/or `<body>` tags, like

```
<html class="android">
```

or

```
<body class="iOS">
```

Quentin's comment is right - trying to write a server-side meta-tag `<%= ResolveUrl(etc) %>` *will not work* because the server isn't running what the javascript writes. The server is finished with its processing already.